# Analog to digital conversion

Tags: microcontroller, avr, adc, c, programming

I am using an Atmega32-A microcontroller and an [AD7798](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD7798_7799.pdf) external ADC. I am able to set the ADC registers and read back ADC values. I have written the following code:

```
  statusreg = AD7798_8(0x40, 0xFF);          // read STATUS register default value
  Id = AD7798_8(0x60, 0xFF);                 // read ID register  default value
  mode = AD7798_16(0x48, 0xFFFF);            // read MODE register default value
  conf = AD7798_16(0x50, 0xFFFF);            // read conf register default value

   AD7798_16(0x10, 0x0010);            // write Configuration reg = 0x0010.  2.5V range  
   value = AD7798_16(0x50, 0xFFFF);         // read Configration register 

   if (value != 0x0010) 
   printf("unexpected conf setting %04x\r\n", value);

   while ((statusreg & 0x80) != 0);                         // wait till ADC is ready 
   adc = AD7798_16(0x58, 0xFFFF);                           // read register 
   printf("ADC value is %04d\r\n", adc);
```

From the above code, I am reading the ADC values. According to the AD7798 datasheet and according to my configuration register setup, I have to find out the analog input voltage using following formula:

> When the ADC is configured for bipolar operation, the output  code is
>   offset binary, with a negative full-scale voltage resulting  in a code
>   of 000...000, a zero differential input voltage resulting  in a code
>   of 100...000, and a positive full-scale input voltage  resulting in a
>   code of 111...111. The output code for any analog  input voltage can
>   be represented as
>
> *Code* = 2<sup>*N* – 1</sup> × [(*AIN* × *GAIN* / *VREF*) + 1]
>
> where:
>   *AIN* is the analog input voltage.
>   *N* = 16 for the AD7798, and *N* = 24 for the AD7799.

I am getting an ADC value of `1EF2`(hex) for 0.6V analog input. I have measured using an oscilloscope. I have calculated the analog input voltage using the above formula and I am getting 0.15V. Here *GAIN* is 1, *VREF* = 2.5V. Which is wrong because I have to get 0.6V. I have converted resultant hex ADC value into decimal `7922` and also binary `0001111011110010`. My analog input voltage is varying from 0V to 0.6V. According to my analog input voltage my ADC output is also changing from `0002` to `1EF2`.

If I change the configuration register setup to any other setup like bipolar to unipolar (from `0x0010` to `0x1010`), at that time I am getting an ADC value of `0000` always. It is giving an ADC value of `0000` for any configuration other than `0x0010` in the configuration register.

More over, I am not able to understand what the following sentence means:

> with a negative full-scale voltage resulting  in a code of 000...000,
>   a zero differential input voltage resulting  in a code of 100...000,
>   and a positive full-scale input voltage  resulting in a code of
>   111...111.

How do I properly convert resultant digital signal to an analog voltage?
Are my ADC readings right or wrong?
Why does my code not work for any other configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AD7798 is a differential ADC.
It has a negative input and a positive input. When configured for bipolar operation:

- When the voltage between in+ and in- is positive (in+ > in-) at full
  scale the output will be all one.
- When the voltage between in+ and in- is 0 (in+ == in-) the output
  will be 1000...0000.
- And When the voltage between in+ and in- is negative (in+ < in-) at
  full scale the output will be all zero.

Comment: I have checked my AIN(+)=0.6(+) and AIN(-)=2.5(+), which means AIN(+)<AIN(-) then i have to get output as all zero's but I am getting values from "0000" to "1EF2".

Comment: Now I understand clearly. ADC is a diffrential amplifier so it will give difference of two inputs as output so here AIN(-) is 2.6 and AIN(+) is 0.6. so I am getting negative -1.9 voltage as output. my ADC result also giving same value. am I correct.

Answer (score 0):

As Blup1980 mentioned, the AD7798 is a ***differential*** ADC. That means that it takes the ***difference*** of the two inputs and converts *that* value.

You have:

AIN(+) = +0.6V with reference to GND
AIN(-) = +2.5V with reference to GND

But the ***difference*** between the two is:

$$AIN = 0.6 - 2.5 = -1.9$$

So we have the following:

$$Code = 2^{N – 1} × [(AIN × GAIN/VREF) + 1]$$
$$7922 = 32768  × [(AIN × 1/2.5) + 1]$$
$$0.24176025390625 = (AIN × 1/2.5) + 1$$
$$-0.75823974609375 = AIN × 1/2.5$$
$$-1.895599365234375 = AIN$$

Which, is correct.

Converted into C code, we have:

```
int      code_dec;
float    code_flt;
float    ain_valu;

/* Initialize variables */
code_dec = 0U;
code_flt = 0.0F;
ain_valu = 0.0F;

code_dec = AD7798_16(0x58, 0xFFFF);                   /* Get Code from ADC */ 
code_flt = (float)code_dec;                           /* Cast Code into float */ 
ain_valu = ((code_flt / 32768.0F) - 1.0F) / 0.4F;     /* Perform calculation */

printf("Voltage is: %f\n", ain_valu);                 /* Print voltage value */
```

Casting the code value into a `float` and then using `float` values during every part of the calculation is good practice. Then you need the `%f` [format specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) to ensure that the value is printed out as a floating point number which will include the negative sign if the value is negative. If you wish to include the positive sign for positive values, use `%+f` instead.

Comment: I have simplified the above formula implemented in c ,      Ain=((adc/32768)-1)/0.416 ; here 0.416=(1/2.5), adc means code value(7922). but the problem is I am not able to print Ain value. I want to print it as float value. It will give negative value. I want to print negative value.

Comment: @verendra See my edit for example C code

Comment: :kyle I have declared code_dec as unsigned int. but still am not able to print. nothing is printing.

Comment: @verendra Nothing is printing? Maybe the problem isn't with the conversion but with the connection to whatever screen you're using. Can you try `printf("Hello World!\n");`? Does that print out?

Comment: Yes hello world is printing and the code also it is printing like "voltage is:  ". Nothing is printing means it is not printing any value.

Comment: @verendra Strange. How about using an explicit value. Does this work: `printf("Float value: %f", 1.234);`?

Comment: No its not working. Just printing like"Float value:  ".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6173/discussion-between-embedded-kyle-and-verendra)