# Formula calculation and printing negative value.

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c

I am successfully reading external ADC value using ATmega32-A.

```
 Unsigned int adc;
 adc = AD7798_16(0x58, 0xFFFF);                           // read register 
       printf("ADC value is %d\r\n", adc);
```

I am getting ADC value as decimal number range between "0 to 65535". I want to convert it into analog voltage using the fallowing formula.

> *Code* = 2<sup>*N* – 1</sup> × [(*AIN* × *GAIN* / *VREF*) + 1]
>
> where:
>   *AIN* is the analog input voltage.
>   *N* = 16 for the AD7798, and *N* = 24 for the AD7799.

I have simplified the formula and calculating

// formula to caluculate analog voltage from digital output :Code = 2N – 1× [(AIN × GAIN/VREF) + 1] 
// GAIN / VREF = 1 / 2.5 => 0.4
// 0.4 Ain = ((adc / 32768) - 1)

float Ain;

Ain=(((((float) adc) / 32768) - 1) / 0.416);

printf("value:%.2f [v]\r\n", Ain);

The above formula returns always negative value. I want to print that negative value. I have tried as above but its not working. How  to print Ain value? here adc is unsigned value so I am converting into float.

I have tried like this also

```
Ain = (((adc / 32768.0) - 1) / 0.416);

printf("value:%.2f [v]\r\n", Ain);
```

but I am not able to print that value.

Comment: I added some example code to [my answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/44946/analog-to-digital-conversion/44961#44961) to your other question. If that doesn't help, let us know what what _is_ being printed out by the code you've given above. If we can see what is being output, we can help figure out what is wrong with the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AVR libraries don't compile in support for printing of floating point values by default. This is to save space on their limited resource environments. You need to tell the compiler and the linker to enable support for this feature.

From the [avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#gaa3b98c0d17b35642c0f3e4649092b9f1) documentation on `vfprintf()`:

> Since the full implementation of all the mentioned features becomes
>   fairly large, three different flavours of `vfprintf()` can be selected
>   using linker options. **The default `vfprintf()` implements all the
>   mentioned functionality except floating point conversions.** A minimized
>   version of `vfprintf()` is available that only implements the very basic
>   integer and string conversion facilities, but only the # additional
>   option can be specified using conversion flags (these flags are parsed
>   correctly from the format specification, but then simply ignored).
>   This version can be requested using the following compiler options:
>
> `-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min`
>
> If the full functionality including the floating point conversions is
>   required, the following options should be used:
>
> `-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm`

(emphasis mine)

Since you are using CodeVisionAVR as we [discussed in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6173/discussion-between-embedded-kyle-and-verendra), they have this option built in to their configuration window as seen on Page 4, Step 9 of [this tutorial](https://www.sjvalley.com/shop/images/stories/PDF/CodeVision%20Tutorial.pdf):

[image]